# How to resolve the error "Could not unbind factory from JNDI: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException?

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly

I have a Java EE app running on a Wildfly 10 server where I see this error after I finish making the number of requests mentioned as the max pool size(in other words if I have 5 set as max pool size I get this error on the 6th try).

Here is my datasource configuration:

```
 <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/ITS" pool-name="ITS" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@prodrac-s..(conn URL here)/connection-url>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <security-domain>encrypted-password-its</security-domain>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>30</idle-timeout-minutes>
                        <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
                        <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
                        <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
                        <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
                    </timeout>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

In my datasource for the Oracle DB I am trying to connect to the max-pool-size is set as 5 and the min-pool-size is 2. I have tried increasing the number to even 20, but I get the error on the 21st attempt.

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
2017-07-26 18:13:18,446 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) - WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = OnCore-FHIR.war_oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver_12_1
2017-07-26 18:13:19,027 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) - WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'OnCore-FHIR.war#its'
2017-07-26 18:13:19,497 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2017-07-26 18:13:19,672 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) - Envers integration enabled? : true
2017-07-26 18:13:21,070 INFO  [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) - HHH000094: Bound factory to JNDI name: hib/oncore/sessions/ITS_FACTORY
2017-07-26 18:13:22,370 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) - RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.company.OnCoreInterface.rest.resources.FhirRestExampleApplicationActivator$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
2017-07-26 18:13:22,417 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) - WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /OnCore-FHIR
2017-07-26 18:13:22,463 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) - WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "OnCore-FHIR.war" (runtime-name : "OnCore-FHIR.war")
2017-07-26 18:13:22,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) - WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:10993/management
2017-07-26 18:13:22,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) - WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:10993
2017-07-26 18:13:22,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) - WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 13623ms - Started 482 of 740 services (435 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2017-07-26 18:15:34,813 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (default task-5) - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-07-26 18:20:53,378 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-21) - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2017-07-26 18:20:53,378 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-21) - javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/jdbc/ITS
2017-07-26 18:22:16,472 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 4) - WFLYSRV0236: Suspending server with no timeout.
2017-07-26 18:22:16,488 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Management Triggered Shutdown) - WFLYSRV0241: Shutting down in response to management operation 'shutdown'
2017-07-26 18:22:16,503 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) - WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = jtds
2017-07-26 18:22:16,503 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) - WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = OnCore-FHIR.war_oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver_12_1
2017-07-26 18:22:16,503 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) - WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = oracleXA
2017-07-26 18:22:16,503 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) - WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
2017-07-26 18:22:16,503 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) - WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:/jdbc/XA_SECURITY_CORE]
2017-07-26 18:22:16,503 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) - WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = sqlserver
2017-07-26 18:22:16,503 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) - WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:/jdbc/XA_ADMINISTRATION_CORE]
2017-07-26 18:22:16,519 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) - WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:/jdbc/XA_ADMIN_SELECT]
2017-07-26 18:22:16,519 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) - WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:/jdbc/XA_SECURITY_SELECT]
2017-07-26 18:22:16,519 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) - WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /OnCore-FHIR
2017-07-26 18:22:16,534 INFO  [org.infinispan.eviction.impl.PassivationManagerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) - ISPN000029: Passivating all entries to disk
2017-07-26 18:22:16,534 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) - WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = sqlserverXA
2017-07-26 18:22:16,534 INFO  [org.infinispan.eviction.impl.PassivationManagerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) - ISPN000030: Passivated 0 entries in 2 milliseconds
2017-07-26 18:22:16,534 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) - WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
2017-07-26 18:22:16,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) - WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped default-host cache from web container
2017-07-26 18:22:16,568 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) - WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'OnCore-FHIR.war#its'
2017-07-26 18:22:16,583 WARN  [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) - HHH000374: Could not unbind factory from JNDI: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error performing unbind [hib/oncore/sessions/ITS_FACTORY]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.unbind(JndiServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry.removeSessionFactory(SessionFactoryRegistry.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.close(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1082)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.close(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:347)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$2$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:237)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$2$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:217)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$2.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0020: Could not resolve service service jboss.naming.context.java.hib.oncore.sessions.ITS_FACTORY
    at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.unbind(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:136)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.unbind(NamingContext.java:318)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.unbind(InitialContext.java:280)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.unbind(InitialContext.java:445)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.unbind(InitialContext.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.unbind(JndiServiceImpl.java:210)
```

I am trying to explicitly close the connection like so:

```
} catch (NamingException ne) {
            System.out.println(ne.getMessage());

        } catch (SQLException ne) {
            System.out.println(ne.getMessage());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            try {
                 HibernateSession.closeITSSession();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("Exception trying to close the Hibernate ITS session: "+ ex);
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Can someone please help here?

Comment: It's likely the container should be handling the lifecycle of Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

The error came due to multiple WARs of the same name being present in the deploy directory.